# Validation of the reference field in mongoengine serializer

Tags: django, serialization, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I'm using **django** with **mongoengine** and **mongoengine-rest-framework**.

As shown in [this article](http://mongo-model-serializer.blogspot.co.uk/#embedding-and-referencing), specifying **related_model_validations** field in **Meta class** of a **Serializer**

```
class Comment(Document):
    post = ReferenceField(Post)
    owner = ReferenceField(User)
    text = StringField(max_length=140)
    isApproved = BooleanField(default=False)



from rest_framework_mongoengine import mongoengine_serializer

class CommentSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        depth = 1
        related_model_validations = {'owner': User, 'post': Post}
        exclude = ('isApproved',)
```

can help to achieve the following result if the document referenced by the **ReferenceField** is missing:

```
{
    "owner":["User with PK ... does not exist."]
}
```

So instead of raising a validation exception, json is modified.

However, this article is written for the old version of **mongoengine-rest-framework** and in the current version there is no field **related_model_validations** in **Serializer Meta class**.

So how to achieve the similar result in the current version of the mongoengine-rest-framework?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, Aleksei.

Currently, if you want to `PUT` or `POST` a comment JSON, you just pass existing owner and post as their `id`s like:

```
{
    post: 2,
    user: aleksei.rozhnov@stackoverflow.com,
    text: "Contrary to the popular belief, Karl Marx and Friedrich Engels are not a couple, but four different people"
}
```

So, if you want to update `Comment`, `Post` and `Author` at the same time, I'm afraid, that's not possible.

In `GET` requests you can get related fields as nested sub-JSONs with non-zero `depth` argument to Serializer, as you did it in your example.